# Where are Hammer and SCM minimax manufactured

Tags: jointer

I'm in a market for a new jointer. I was undecided between SCM FS30c or Hammer A31 30.
I thought that both of them were manufactured in EU. 
Sale reps from both refer to the other as "polished, pricy" china and their products being proudly manufactured in EU.
I suspect that both are made to a certain degree in China...I'm just not sure how much.

Comment: Does it really matter where they're made? They are good, bad or average regardless of the place of manufacture. Quality is completely separate to whether they're labelled as "made in the EU" or "made in China", there are very good and very poor products (and many in between) from China and from Europe.

Comment: Further, with how global economies work, where a tool is made today may not be where it is made tomorrow. Jointers are moderately large tools, but not so large that a factory cannot be retooled to make a run in a modest amount of time. Not to mention that, again, given globalism, parts are probably manufactured almost anywhere, subsystems assembled in another place, and final assembly in yet another place. So even if a company said "Proudly Made in Megatopia" it's hard to know what "made" means in this era of capitalism.

Comment: @Graphus It does to some people, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the opinionated portion (are they worth the price) and focus on where the machines are made. You can ask about the value of each machine as a separate question, but make sure to keep it from being opinion-based - stick to performance, common failures, etc.

Comment: @mmathis, yes but my point was *should it*? People have biases, sure we all know this. Now some of them are more preference than bias in the pejorative sense. But plenty *are* the latter and I don't mind being the whipping boy for pointing out that this isn't necessarily reflective of reality.

Comment: @Graphus Country of origin can be indicative of quality - though not always, which I think is what you're getting at. But country of origin can also speak to work environments, human rights issues, excessive shipping, to name a few, which go beyond the functionality of the tool itself.

Comment: I was not expecting a debate about whether it matters or not. I thought that someone knows how and where they are made and could give me some insight. There can be only one reason why someone moves manufacturing of such machines (same machines that used to be made in the country of claimed origin) to China - cost. And lower cost comes with a price. It can be human rights issues, environmental, but also quality. Let's admit it, all 3 play they role. So in the end, all 3 matter to me and hence I'd like to buy a product that's made in EU where all those issues tend to be more under control.

Comment: That's fair enough Michal, but you realise that "made in EU" will realistically mean **assembled** in EU for almost everything? No company on earth makes all their switches, bearings, resistors, capacitors etc. in-house. Most are made overseas, and predominantly in China. So even shopping for the label you want you're not really getting what it seems to imply, Then there's basic raw materials, who manufactures the majority of the world's steel, aluminium alloys, plastics, pigments and binders? China. So actually you can't realistically avoid the human rights or environmental issues.

Comment: @graphus, you're right. SCM for instance I heard is has the cast iron production completely under their umbrella. I was hoping that people who actually saw/were part of production/manufacturing of such machines would give their opinion. But that'd probably go against the NDA so after some considerations I'll close this answer. I've bought Minimax FS30 anyways :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even if we could determine this today to satisfy the question behind the question, it's sure to change tomorrow. This will never be a useful Q&A.

Comment: San Marino, Italy, and Brazil is where "Production" is done in 2021. Who knows where all the parts are made. Who knows where production will be done tomorrow.